# Disable full keyboard and mouse when console of c is running in window OS

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is it possible to disable full keyboard and mouse when I run my c program in window OS. Kindly guide me how can I make it possible.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying you want to disable the keyboard and mouse so that *no other* application can use them while yours is running?

Comment: Yes when my application run no one can interact with any application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [`BlockInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290(VS.85).aspx)?